# iOS: How to retrieve code-signing identifier

Tags: ios, code-signing

For diagnostic purposes, it is sometimes wished to be able to read the code signing identifier for the running app.

This information exists in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file within the bundle of the app, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>Happy</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
    <string>7YCRDE64W6</string>
    </array>
```

What code-snippet can be used to read this information?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Objective-C code which can do this job for us:

```
-(NSString*_Nullable)codeSignId
{
    NSString *provisPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded.mobileprovision" ofType:nil];
    NSData *provisData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:provisPath];

    NSData *tokApplicationIdentifierPrefix = [@"ApplicationIdentifierPrefix" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *tokStringStart = [@"<string>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *tokStringEnd = [@"</string>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    #define RangeOK(rng) rng.location != NSNotFound
    NSUInteger len = provisData.length;

    NSRange range1 = [provisData rangeOfData:tokApplicationIdentifierPrefix options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];
    if (RangeOK(range1)) { //found ApplicationIdentifierPrefix
        NSRange range2 = [provisData rangeOfData:tokStringStart options:0 range:NSMakeRange(range1.location, len-range1.location)];
        if (RangeOK(range2)) { //found <string>
            NSRange range3 = [provisData rangeOfData:tokStringEnd options:0 range:NSMakeRange(range2.location, len-range2.location)];
            if (RangeOK(range3)) { //found </string>
                NSString *appIdPrefix = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[provisData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(range2.location+8, range3.location - range2.location -8)] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                return appIdPrefix;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

EDIT

I have just learned that sometimes the file `embedded.mobileprovision` contains different values for `ApplicationIdentifierPrefix` and for `TeamIdentifier`. I would be glad to learn the differences between these two.